# .Net MVC 4 CAS Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cas

I need to authenticate User from a central **CAS**. The assumption are these:

1. The UserId for authentication is in a Request Header
2. The roles for authorization are given by a web service.
3. The application must cache the authorization phase.

I've tried this:

In the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string SiteMinderHeaderToken = "SM_USER";
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null || !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var userSSO = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[SiteMinderHeaderToken];
            GenericIdentity webIdentity = new GenericIdentity(userSSO, "SiteMinder");

            string[] roles = { "ROLE1", "ROLE2" };
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(webIdentity, roles);
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;



            // System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userSSO, true);

        }
    }
```

In the Web.config

```
<authentication mode="None"   />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The problem is that **for every request**, the `HttpContext.Current.User` **is always null**, and every time all the authentication and authorization phase are done.

If I uncomment

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userSSO, true);
```

All is fine, after the first request the User is authenticated.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to call System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie even if there isn't FormAuthentication?
2. Is there a way to do it better?
3. Are there some security issues doing this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. FormsAuthentication in this case is just storing the users session.
   Here's some more info: Understanding the Forms Authentication Ticket and Cookie https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910443/
2. You can set the auth cookie this way, but if would like to store more of the users info within the session, I would recommend using claims.
3. FormsAuthentication cookie is secure.  "The ticket is encrypted and signed using the  configuration element of the server's Machine.config file. ASP.NET 2.0 uses the decryptionKey and the new decryption attribute of the  element to encrypt forms authentication tickets."  There's more information in the link I gave above.  I guess the only security issue would be how the user is accessing your code "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userSSO, true);"

Try looking into Owin Authentication to store the users session.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Here's an example of how I use it in my MVC project.

**Installed nugget packages:**

- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

**Created OwinConfig.cs file (in my App_Start folder):**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.OwinConfig))]

namespace MyProject
{
using System.Web.Security;

using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;

using Owin;

/// <summary>
/// The startup.
/// </summary>
public class OwinConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">
    /// The app.
    /// </param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        });
    }
}
}
```

**Code I use to log a user in:**

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, 1)),
    new Claim("CustomClaim", "My bio or something"), 
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "set_username")
};
var userWithClaims = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = owinContext.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(userWithClaims);
```

**And then I access the stored claims by creating IdentityExtensions.cs class (also in my app_start folder):**

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetCustomClaim(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }

        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        return ci != null ? ci.FindFirstValue("CustomClaim") : null;
    }
    private static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }

        var claim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
        return claim != null ? claim.Value : null;
    }
}
```

**So in my controller I could just call:**

```
string customClaim  = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetCustomClaim();
```

**Then finally, to logout I would use:**

```
var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = owinContext.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, nice format and info, but it seems a bit off topic, away from my questions.

Comment: 1. FormsAuthentication is just storing a session.  2. My way above is a better way to store the session with additional data.  3. FormsAuthentication stores an encrypted cookie, so its secure.